# (Scheme) Find distance between two words in a list?

Tags: scheme

Ok, so I'm trying to write a function that finds the distance between two elements in a list, s and t.

For example, if s = bob and t = pizza:

```
(d 'bob 'pizza '(bob blah blah pizza))
```

it would return: 3

This is what I have so far.

```
(define dist
 (lambda (s t line)
  (cond
   [(equal? s (car line))
     [(equal? t (car (cdr line)))
        1]]
   [else (add1 (dist s t (cdr line)))])))
```

For some reason, it's not working. Help?

Thanks!

Comment: My Scheme is a little rusty, but those `[` and `]` look out of place. And since (I think) you only have two clauses, would not an if be simpler?

Comment: @crashmstr using `[]` in place of `()` is allowed, and it's useful for clarity. For example, for differentiating between a `cond`'s clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed code in the question is not going to work, it's just checking if the two elements are contiguous in the list. Let's try a different approach altogether - split the problem in smaller subproblems, begin by defining a procedure that returns the index of an element in a list, counting indexes from zero:

```
(define (index-of elt lst)
  <???>) ; ToDo
```

With the above procedure in place, and assuming that both `s` and `t` are present in the list and `t` appears after `s`, it's easy to find the solution to the question:

```
(define dist
  (lambda (s t line)
    (- (index-of t line)
       (index-of s line))))
```

For example:

```
(dist 'bob 'pizza '(bob blah blah pizza))
=> 3
```

For extra credit, consider the cases where one or both of the elements are not present in the list (so `index-of` should return a value indicating this, say, `#f`), or when `s` appears after `t` in the list.

Comment: Separating it makes it much easier. I think I got it now

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking (cdr line) in the last step you are throwing away bob even if bob is the first element.

You need to take care of 3 and maybe 4 cases.
Where s and t match the first two elements you do fine.
Where s matches and t doesn't you need to add 1 to a recursive call using line with the 2nd element removed.   Something like (cons (car line) (cdr (cdr line))).
Where s doesn't match you need to remove the car of line and try again.
Unless you are sure s and t will both occur and in order you need a terminating condition(s) to take care of running out of line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that iterates down the list looking for 's' and 't' each time.  When both have been seen, the result is returned; otherwise, continue looking:

```
(define (dist s t line)
  (let looking ((l line) (n 0) (i #f))
    (and (not (null? l))
         (let ((item (car l)))
           (if (or (equal? item s)
                   (equal? item t))
               (if (not i)
                   (looking (cdr l) (+ n 1) n) ; found first, continue
                   (- n i))                    ; found second, done
               (looking (cdr l) (+ n 1) i)))))); continue looking
```